# How to remember exact scroll position in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my VC, I've table view. I want to remember the exact scroll position so that when user comes back to this view I can scroll to the same position. My requirement is that I've to reload data when user comes back to view.

I've tried using content offset method but this offset is going way off the table height so this solution doesn't work for me.

I've tried saving indexPath and scrolling to this position but this doesn't give exact position. I've to specify middle, top or bottom which is not exact position.

So how do we remember exact scroll position and scroll to that position after reloading data in table?

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: scrollToSavedIndexPath, at: UITableView.ScrollPosition.middle, animated: false)
```

Comment: As mentioned below, `contentOffset` is the correct way to do this. If it is not working, then perhaps your cell heights or `contentInset.top` is changing when you're reloading - or you're re-applying the `contentOffset` before reloading?

Comment: How are you setting the heights of tableViewCell? Are these dynamic? If it is, that might be the issue for changes in contentOffset. Try giving a Constant height for tableViewCells and see if it works then. Then we can discuss how to resolve that particular problem.

Comment: Cell heights are all fixed in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUESTION: I just saw that you mentioned that contentOffset wasn't working for you. Can you try the method again by printing out the contentOffset value each time? That's a good starting point to understand why the offset method is not working for you.

Use the following to save the scroll position:

```
 let offset = tableView.contentOffset
```

Then set the scroll position as follows:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: false)
```

Comment: Whilst this is the correct answer, the OP has said that `contentOffset` is not working for him, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: I've ViewController inside that I've search bar at the top which shows/hides when search icon is tapped. Below search bar I've Segments. Below segment I've TableView.

Comment: The solution may/will work. Issue is with fetching data which seems to be getting too complex and I can't get head around it. Tx for help.